# Manual Core Data Requests in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Given that `@FetchRequest` does not support dynamic predicates (eg, I could not update the "month" in a calendar and re-query for the events I have scheduled in that month), I am trying to get a manual request to work.

The `@FetchRequest` already works if I don't try to make a dynamic predicate, so I assume the core data is configured to work correctly.

In my `SceneDelegate` I have:

```
            guard let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
            fatalError("Unable to read managed object context.")
        }

        let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

and in my `AppDelegate`:

```
  lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
      let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Transactions")
      container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
          if let error = error as NSError? {
              fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          }
      })
      return container
  }()
```

If I try doing a manual request in my `ContentView` like:

```
let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Employees")

    do {
        let employees = try managedObjectContext.fetch(employeesFetch) as! [Employees]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
    }
```

This fails because `Exception   NSException *   "+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Employees'"

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: In my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59168754/264802 I show how to do manual fetches quite easily.

Comment: There are a lot in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+%40FetchRequest+predicate