# Setup managedObjectContext on SceneDelegate SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I followed a tutorial of an Onboarding screen but it seems it's mostly an adaptation of UIKit, on `AppDelegate` I get the following error in purple:

`Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000018d5880>`

I believe it's the way it's setup in SceneDelegate that the managedObjectContext is not being passed along to the next screen, here is how I have it:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        // Set the MotherView as the root view
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MotherView().environmentObject(ViewRouter()))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

That works if I don't use core data of course. How can Integrate ViewRouter() here:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    // Get the managed object context from the shared persistent container.
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Create the SwiftUI view and set the context as the value for the managedObjectContext environment keyPath.
    // Add `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` in the views that will need the context.
    let contentView = MotherView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        // Set the MotherView as the root view
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I went to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166513/coredata-and-swiftui-context-in-environment-is-not-connected-to-a-persistent-st) post but it doesn't do the trick for me, is there a way I could fix this in the SceneDelegate?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166513/coredata-and-swiftui-context-in-environment-is-not-connected-to-a-persistent-st . You might wanna take a look there

Comment: Hi @lennartk, I already went through that post and I don't know how to fix it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach environment object to constructed content view in any place, for example as below

```
let contentView = MotherView()
                     .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
                     .environmentObject(ViewRouter())
```