# Getting nilError from CoreData

Tags: swiftui

Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600002aa5520>

This is the error message and my App crashes
It crashes in try when Saving Data to Core Data
My print statements work well:

titleString: Qqq

The title of the list: Optional("Qqq")

Not sure what to check?

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddNewList: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@State private var titleString: String = ""
@State private var isAlertPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $titleString)
            Button {
                self.saveList()
                isAlertPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $isAlertPresented) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Empty Title!"),
                    message: Text("Please set a title"),
                    dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!"))
                )
            }
        }

    }
    
    private func saveList() {
        let newList = ListNames(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        newList.title = titleString
        print("titleString: \(titleString)")
        print("The title of the list: \(String(describing: newList.title))")
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            //Always a good idea to dimiss after saving
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            #if DEBUG
            fatalError()
            #endif
        }
    }
}

//This is the App

import SwiftUI

@main
struct MasterListApp: App {

let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            GridViewPage()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        } 
    }
}
}


// This is the landing page
struct ListFrontPage: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: ListNames.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ListNames.title, ascending: false)]) var listNames: FetchedResults<ListNames>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            List() {
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                ForEach (listNames) { listName in
                    Text("test")
                }
            }

            Spacer()
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: AddNewList()) {
                     Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").font(.system(size: 64))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CoreData and SwiftUI: Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166513/coredata-and-swiftui-context-in-environment-is-not-connected-to-a-persistent-st)

Comment: No other functions are being used currently.